# Allowing URL access only via an iFrame and prevent from direct access in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a website folder with some content in PHP. And I want it to be accessed only via iframe. And want to prevent using direct URL access.

**Allow access** `<iframe  src="example.com/chocos.php"></iframe>`

And **redirect accessing** the `example.com/chocos.php` URL if directly accessed.

I have added a javascript for this purpose.

`<script>if(window==window.top) {
    window.location.href = "/";
    }
 </script>`

But I want to do this using PHP. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: PHP has no way of knowing whether the browser will display the requested resource in an iframe or not. A PHP script is ultimately a program that causes a bunch of text/binary being sent over a network connection. It does receive some (spoofable) info about who's requesting it, but not whether it'll end up as `src` of an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with php using cookies:

On the main page that have the iframe code, save a new cookie without setting an expiration date for it:

```
setcookie("allowAccess", 1);
```

then, on the file that is loaded into the iframe, "chocos.php" in your case:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['allowAccess'])
    {
       //your content here;
    }
else
    {
       //your redirection here
    }
```

so if the user doesn't visit the main page, the alloweAccess cookie won't set in the browser, so the iframe page will do the redirection as you want.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I use this simple code to check whenever my PHP file is accessed directly or not:

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE"] != "same-origin")
{
    die("Access denied!");
}
```